# Bootstrap's dark table heads become hoverable. Can I do something about it (other than specifying style manually)?

Tags: html, jquery, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I like hoverable tables. But I noticed that if I include the `table-dark` class in my `<thead>` element (I like dark table headings as well), it becomes hoverable as if it's a body row (which is silly). If I remove it, everything's fine. Is it standard behavior? **Can I have hoverable tables with dark headings in Bootstrap 4 without resorting to manual measures like `class="bg-dark text-light"`?**

Also, just for fun, try adding the `table-dark` class to the `thead tr` element and see what happens (weird stuff!)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change class of thead, It should be 'thead-dark',

Need to change line no. 13 code `<thead class="thead-dark">`

You can check this pen: https://codepen.io/himanipanchal/pen/LYgVRYg

Comment: Thank you! Though, it's weird a bit: for some reason, it works despite the fact that `thead-dark` class is not specified in Bootstrap's CSS! I examined it with Devtools. Also, it seems only `thead-dark` works but not, for instance, `thead-primary`. Mystery!